# Akka ask pattern: how to make request and replies context-aware?

Tags: akka, akka-typed

For a University assignment, I have to implement a simulation of the Raft protocol in Akka (I am using Akka typed, using Behaviors).
In the Raft protocol, interactions between actors have a 1:1 mapping between a request and a response; responses must be delivered in a timely manner.
Therefore, it makes sense to use the `ask` pattern as demonstrated by the documentation in the [Request-Response with ask between two actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#request-response-with-ask-between-two-actors) example.

In my implementation, requests and responses must be context-aware: this means that, when an actor that performed a query receives a response, it must know what query the response was for. The example in the documentation suggests to include a query ID in the message.

What I need to solve can be described with the following example:

- Actor A sends a query with ID=1 to actor B (it includes the query ID in the message).
- B does not reply in time (the network, or B itself, may be slow), thus A re-issues a query with ID=2 to B.
- Actor B receives the query with ID=1, and replies to actor A (including the query ID in the message).
- Actor A receives B's reply with ID=1. A knows that the last query it sent had ID=2, thus must NOT process the reply but wait for the one with ID=2.

I think that, to "filter" replies that do not have a correct query ID, I can put a [BehaviorInterceptor](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/BehaviorInterceptor.html) in actor A that checks that the ID in the reply matches the expected query ID.

To summarize:

- Actor A writes in a hashmap the query ID to be expected from actor B's next reply,
- The interceptor uses this hashmap to check the ID in the reply.
  Is this a good design?

Moreover, I don't understand whether `ask` is blocking or not.
Ideally, I would like to use `ask` in a non-blocking way: actor A `ask`s actor B, and, while waiting for B's reply, A can do other operations.
While waiting for B's reply, actor A can also change its behavior if needed (also a Behavior that does not handle B's replies).

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ask between two actors (using the `ActorContext`) is non-blocking.

Since the high watermark of the requests to a given target is an important part of protocol state for the actor, I would just store it in the asking actor's state (e.g. in Scala a `Map[ActorRef[Request], Int]`).  The adapted response contains the target and the id it's in response to (you define how this is incorporated when performing the ask); when receiving the adapted response, the first thing is comparing the id in the response to the high watermark for the target.

In Scala, for example:

```scala
sealed trait RequestA
case class QueryB(target: ActorRef[RequestB]) extends RequestA
case class ResponseFromB(target: ActorRef[RequestB], id: Int, resp: ResponseB) extends RequestA
case class BTimedOut(target: ActorRef[RequestB], id: Int) extends RequestA

sealed trait RequestB

def buildRequestB(id: Int)(replyTo: ResponseB): RequestB = ???

sealed trait ResponseB

def aBehavior(highWater: Map[ActorRef[RequestB], Int]): Behavior[RequestA] =
  Behaviors.receive { (context, msg) =>
    case QueryB(target) =>
      implicit val timeout: Timeout = 10.seconds

      val nextHighwater = highWater.get(target).map(_ + 1).getOrElse(0)

      // request is sent and received "in the background"
      context.ask(target, buildRequestB(nextHighwater)) {
        case Success(resp) => ResponseFromB(target, nextHighwater, resp)
        case Failure(_) => BTimedOut(target, nextHighwater)
      }

      aBehavior(highWater + (target -> nextHighwater))

    case ResponseFromB(target, id, resp) =>
      if (highWater.get(target).contains(id)) {
        context.log.info("Accepting response: {}", resp)
        Behaviors.same
      } else {
        context.log.info("Ignoring response: {}", resp)
        Behaviors.same
      }

    case BTimedOut(target, id) =>
      context.log.warning("Ask of {} (sequence ID {}) timed out", target, id)
      Behaviors.same
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, your response removes the additional complexity of the Interceptor and matches my intuition. Just another clarification: What happens if, while `ask` is working in the background, the Actor changes to another behavior? For instance, a behavior that does not handle `ResponseFromB` nor `BTimedOut`? Will the message be delivered to deadLetters, right?

Comment: In typed, an actor should handle every message in its type, or alse explicitly ignore the ones it doesn't want to handle via `Behaviors.ignore` or `Behaviors.unhandled`... the difference between those two is that the latter publishes an event to Akka's event stream that the message wasn't handled.

Comment: Sorry, but I feel a little confused. Should an actor __necessarily__ `ignore` all the messages it should not handle? Can't the new actor behavior simply return a Receive that does not match such message? As a concrete example of what I want to obtain (I can't put it here for space limitations), I prepared [this note](https://pastebin.com/QBZmj70h).

Comment: There are a lot of bugs that arise from inadvertently not handling a message (e.g. because "that can't happen").  In Scala, typically, not explicitly ignoring/unhandling a message can cause the compiler to reject code, so I always handle every message.  I can't therefore answer what happens when an unhandled message is received.  It probably results in an unhandled event on the event stream (entailing a performance hit).

Comment: I do not have enough experience to envision a scenario where this would cause a bug, but I trust you nonetheless: I take your advice as a best practice. Is it possible to instruct the actor to automatically `ignore` messages for which it is not interested? In Akka classic, one can do [`matchAny`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#receive-messages) at the end of the chain. What about Akka typed? I think that [`onAnyMessage`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/javadsl/BehaviorBuilder.html#onAnyMessage%28akka.japi.function.Function%29) is the proper equivalent.

Comment: Levi, sorry to bother you again, but I think there's something wrong in using `Behaviors.ignore` to ignore undesired messages. I think `Behaviors.same` should be used instead. What I wanted to achieve is: if an actor receives a message which should not handle in its FSM state, it should simply ignore it and continue as normal. If I put `ignore`, not only will it ignore that message, but also [all subsequent ones](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/javadsl/Behaviors$.html#ignore()), including the correct ones (thus, the actor deviates from the expected behavior).